# Convergence/divergence of a series: $a_1 = 2$, $a_{n+1}=\frac{5n + 1}{4n+3}a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Given the series

The terms of a series are deﬁned recursively by the equations
$$a_1 = 2\\
a_{n+1}=\frac{5n + 1}{4n+3}a_n$$

Determine whether the summation of $a_n$
converges or diverges.

Comment: So what have you done and what ideas do you have?

Comment: Are you really asking about the summation of $(a_n)$, or about the limiting behavior of the _sequence_?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that for $n > 2$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1 \implies a_{n+1} > a_n > 0$.

Thus, the **summation** (I'm assuming from $n=1$ to $n = \infty$) of this strictly increasing (for $n > 2$) sequence is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

For converging series 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} <1$$ 
  by Ratio Test

but here 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} =\frac{5n + 1}{4n+3}=5/4>1 $$
 so
It diverges

Comment: converges if $|a_{n+1}/a_n|\to 1$? This is not true, consider the Harmonic Series for example.

Comment: $\sum_k 1/k$ diverges and $k/(k+1)\to 1$ and $\sum_k 1/k^2$ converges and $k^2/(k+1)^2 \to 1$. The series converges if $a_n$ is non zero for all $n$ and $\limsup |a_{n+1}/a_n| \to L <1$

Comment: yea, may be u were right. but now?

Comment: No, the series converges if the the $\limsup |a_{n+1}/a_n| = L$ and $L<1$ (or the limit when exists but is stronger to consider $\limsup$, because always exists), If $L=1$ the test is inconclusive as was shown above, if $\liminf |a_{n+1}/a_n|>1$ the  series diverges (assuming of course that the $a_n$'s are non-zero).

Comment: now it may look right,